# Characterization of maps with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-equivariant lifts.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I'm interested in characterizing maps $f:\mathbb{R}P^k\to\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ that lift to a $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-equivariant map $\tilde{f}:S^k\to S^\infty$.

For $k\geq 2$ I have been able to prove:
$$
(1)\;f\text{ lifts to a }\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\text{- equivariant map} \iff f_\#:\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^k)\to \pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^\infty) \text{ is an isomorphism} \; (2)
$$
where $f_\#$ is the induced map on the fundamental group.

But I'm much more interested in a statement about the induced maps on (co)homology with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients.

In particular: Is the following equivalence true? If so, how does one prove this?

> $$(1)\iff f_*:H_k(\mathbb{R}P^k;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\to H_k(\mathbb{R}P^\infty;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\text{ is an isomorphism}\quad (3)$$
>   Or even better:
>   $$(1)\iff f_*:H_i(\mathbb{R}P^k;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\to H_i(\mathbb{R}P^\infty;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\text{ is an isomorphism for }i\leq k \quad (4)$$

**Edit:** I have been able to prove the above statements.
In fact $(1)$ is equivalent to the following statements (coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$):

- $\exists i\in\{1,\ldots, k\}$ such that $ f_*:H_i(\mathbb{R}P^k)\to H_i(\mathbb{R}P^\infty)$ is an isomorphism
- $\forall i\in\{1,\ldots, k\}:$ $ f_*:H_i(\mathbb{R}P^k)\to H_i(\mathbb{R}P^\infty)$ is an isomorphism
- $\exists i\in\{1,\ldots, k\}$ such that $ f^*:H^i(\mathbb{R}P^\infty)\to H^i(\mathbb{R}P^k)$ is an isomorphism
- $\forall i\in\{1,\ldots, k\}:$ $ f^*:H^i(\mathbb{R}P^\infty)\to H^i(\mathbb{R}P^k)$ is an isomorphism

Since I now know the answer to my own question I will probably delete it soon. At least if there is no activity here during the next few days.

Comment: My own preference would be for you to type up your own answer (or at least a sketch).  The system allows (and even encourages) you to do so.